# Can someone help me convert this Curl request into node.js?

Tags: node.js, curl, plaid

I'm working with Webhooks and I am trying to run a Curl request from my node.js code. I'm using the npm *request* package to do this. I'm having trouble finding the proper way to convert the Curl request to code in my application that will send the request.

This is the Curl request:

```
curl -X POST https://tartan.plaid.com/connect \
  -d client_id=test_id \
  -d secret=test_secret \
  -d username=plaid_test \
  -d password=plaid_good \
  -d type=wells \
  -d options='{
      "webhook":"http://requestb.in/",
      "login_only":true }'
```

This works fine when I run it in my terminal so I know the credentials work and it is talking to the server.

Here is my Node.js code:

```
var request = require('request');

var opt = {
  url: 'https://tartan.plaid.com/connect',
  data: {
    'client_id': 'test_id',
    'secret': 'test_secret',
    'username': 'plaid_test',
    'password': 'plaid_good',
    'type': 'wells',
    'webhook': 'http://requestb.in/', 
    'login_only': true
  }
};

request(opt, function (error, response, body) {
  console.log(body)
});
```

It should return an *item* but all I am getting is:

```
{
  "code": 1100,
  "message": "client_id missing",
  "resolve": "Include your Client ID so we know who you are."
}
```

All the credentials are from the Plaid website and they work in my terminal just fine so I think it's just the way I am writing my Node.js code that is causing the problem.

If anyone could help my find the right way to write the node code so that it does what the curl request does in the terminal that would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use `form:` instead of `data:` in your options. Hopefully that will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The default method for [request](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback) is GET. You want a POST, so you have to set that as a parameter. You also have to send the data as JSON according to the [documentation](https://plaid.com/docs/api/). So I believe this should work:

```
var opt = {
  url: 'https://tartan.plaid.com/connect',
  method: "POST",
  json: {
    'client_id': 'test_id',
    'secret': 'test_secret',
    'username': 'plaid_test',
    'password': 'plaid_good',
    'type': 'wells',
    'webhook': 'http://requestb.in/', 
    'login_only': true
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

See [explainshell: `curl -X -d`](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=curl+-X+-d) for an explanation of what your curl command actually does.

- You send a *POST* request
- You send data using using the content-type *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*

To replicate that with [request](https://github.com/request/request) you have to configure it accordingly:

```
var opt = {
  url: 'https://tartan.plaid.com/connect',
  form: {
    // ...
  }
};

request.post(opt, function (error, response, body) {
  console.log(body)
});
```

See [application/x-www-form-urlencoded](https://github.com/request/request#applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-url-encoded-forms) for more examples.